# Send the random color of the card item to onClick

Tags: android

I have RecyclerView + card. In the card, one element must be of a random color. 
I created an array of colors and implemented the task in this way -

```
 @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.model_poem, parent, false);

    int[] androidColors = view.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidColors);
    int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
    if (frameLayout != null) {
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
    }

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

When you click on a card, the activaty with full information opens and the color of the toolbar must coincide the color of the element in the card.

```
     public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titleTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
       ..............
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);

          itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReadActivity.class);
                long poemId = (Long) v.getTag();
                intent.putExtra("randomAndroidColor", frameLayout.getBackground().toString());
                onPoemClickListener.onPoemClick(poemId);
            }
        });
    }
}

public interface OnPoemClickListener {
    void onPoemClick(long poemId);

}
```

class activity

```
    public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    public static final String EXTRA_POEM_ID = "poem_id";
   .....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.read);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       tv_Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
      .......
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    randomAndroidColor = intent.getStringExtra("randomAndroidColor");
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(randomAndroidColor));
    poemId = getIntent().getLongExtra(EXTRA_POEM_ID, -1);
        if (poemId == -1) {
            finish();
        }

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(
                0, 
                null, 
                this 
        );
}
```

Application crashes with error E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: rodionova.lyubov.brodsky, PID: 31328
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rodionova.lyubov.brodsky/rodionova.lyubov.brodsky.activity.ReadActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think the easiest thing to do would be to save the color `int` as the FrameLayout's *tag*, and then retrieve the tag when you want to pass it to the activity. This way you don't have to worry about handling the background drawable and/or converting it to a color.

Set the tag:

```
int[] androidColors = view.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidColors);
int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
if (frameLayout != null) {
    frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
    frameLayout.setTag(randomAndroidColor);
}
```

Pass the tag value to the activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReadActivity.class);
    long poemId = (Long) v.getTag();
    intent.putExtra("randomAndroidColor", (int) frameLayout.getTag());
    onPoemClickListener.onPoemClick(poemId);
    // presumably you trimmed out something that actually starts the Intent
}
```

And retrieve the color:

```
// randomAndroidColor should be an int now
randomAndroidColor = intent.getIntExtra("randomAndroidColor", 0);
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is frameLayout.getBackground() not returning a color int, it return a drawable and so when you use toString() on that drawable, it won't return a color string but something else instead. 
You can use Ben P's coding way to solve this problem, it's nice.